# ListView won't show up while in TabItem

Tags: c#, wpf, listview, tabcontrol, tabitem

Okay so I am trying to make this application where I want different things to show up on different tabs.

I created a tab control, and I have "Map View" and "Text View".  I haven't yet started on Map View so its empty currently.  "Text View" is supposed to have a ListView and a WebBrowser in it.

I had these items in the application before using the tabs, and they showed up and worked just fine.  But now that I am trying to put them inside a TabItem, the ListView will NOT show up no matter what I do.

The WebBrowser shows up fine, but the ListView, despite numerous attempts to bring it to the front, will not show up.  It won't show up in the design screen, nor will it show when the program is run.  I can select it, and if I copy-paste the XAML to another part of the page (no longer inside the TabControl) it is perfectly visible again.  I have no idea why this is at all, been trying to figure it out for over an hour now.

```
    <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="506" Margin="278,46,0,0"     VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="753" x:Name="TextMapGrid" Background="#FFEEE1E1">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <TabControl HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="21" Margin="-1,-21,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="136">
            <TabItem Header="Text View">
                <Grid Background="#FFE5E5E5">
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition/>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <WebBrowser x:Name="RSSWeb" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="363" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="746" Margin="0,135,-620,-498" Grid.ColumnSpan="2"/>
                    <ListView x:Name="RSSList" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="121" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="746" MouseLeftButtonUp="RSSList_MouseLeftButtonUp" Margin="0,-1,-620,-120" Background="White" Grid.ColumnSpan="2">
                        <ListView.View>
                            <GridView>
                                <GridViewColumn Header="Read" Width="50" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Read}"/>
                                <GridViewColumn Header="Title" Width="300" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Title}"/>
                                <GridViewColumn Header="Date" Width="110" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Date}"/>
                                <GridViewColumn Header="Link" Width="343" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding URL}"/>
                            </GridView>
                        </ListView.View>
                    </ListView>

                </Grid>
            </TabItem>
            <TabItem Header="Map View" Margin="-2,-2,-2,-1">
                <Grid Background="#FFE5E5E5">

                </Grid>
            </TabItem>
        </TabControl>

    </Grid>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are putting both your listview and webbrowser in a single cell grid.
Also, remove the Margin and Grid.Columnspan attributes on your listview and webbrowser.

You can either wrap them in a StackPanel e.g.

```
<StackPanel>
    <ListView x:Name="RSSList" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="121" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="746" MouseLeftButtonUp="RSSList_MouseLeftButtonUp" Margin="0,-1,-620,-120" Background="White" Grid.ColumnSpan="2">
        <ListView.View>
            <GridView>
                <GridViewColumn Header="Read" Width="50" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Read}"/>
                <GridViewColumn Header="Title" Width="300" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Title}"/>
                <GridViewColumn Header="Date" Width="110" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Date}"/>
                <GridViewColumn Header="Link" Width="343" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding URL}"/>
            </GridView>
        </ListView.View>
    </ListView>
    <WebBrowser x:Name="RSSWeb" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="363" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="746" Margin="0,135,-620,-498" Grid.ColumnSpan="2"/>
</StackPanel>
```

or add row definitions to your grid and assign them to their own row.

```
<Grid Background="#FFE5E5E5">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition />
        <RowDefinition />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <WebBrowser Grid.Row="1" ... Rest of code omitted for brevity />
    <ListView Grid.Row="0" ...Rest of code omitted for brevity />
</Grid>
```

EDIT: Simple example demonstrating that the concept works.
You can create a new window/usercontrol and try the code sample below.

```
<Grid>
    <TabControl>
        <TabItem Header="Stack Panel example">
            <StackPanel>
                <TextBlock Text="ListView" />
                <ListView Height="100" Margin="2"/>
                <TextBlock Text="Web Browser" />
                <WebBrowser Height="100" Margin="2" />
            </StackPanel>
        </TabItem>
        <TabItem Header="Grid example">
            <Grid>
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition />
                    <RowDefinition />
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <ListView Grid.Row="0" Height="100" Margin="2"/>
                <WebBrowser Grid.Row="1" Height="100" Margin="2"/>
            </Grid>
        </TabItem>
    </TabControl>
</Grid>
```

Comment: Neither of these worked.  Having the WebBrowser below the ListView didn't work either.  Also, putting the ListView by itself on the second tab item (Header="Map View" one) still didn't show the ListView.  So being by itself on its own grid still did not make it show up.

Comment: Did you remove the Margin attributes on the ListView and WebBrowser?

Comment: For reference, this is a picture of the entire application.  The empty grey area in the upper right is where the ListView is supposed to show up.  The white box below it is the WebBrowser that still shows.

http://i.imgur.com/CDDegas.jpg

Comment: I did not remove the Margins.  EDIT: When I did remove them, the web browser moved to the top of the tabitem grid, now overlapping the listview.

Comment: I've edited the code samples to move the WebBrowser below the ListView. I have also provided a simple example to show you that the concept does work. With WPF, you really shouldn't be using margins to position your control elements. You should use containers to control layout.

Comment: Well nothing is working, I tried your solution in a new project and it worked fine.  I'm going to just try and find some workaround, thanks anyways.